# How to make a pattern match 4 digits with at least one letter?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following solution:

```
str = "0e4f9a4fdcfb351397b65cdcabcd0673d768cf59"    
patten = re.compile("\d(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\d]{4}\d")

searchObj = patten.findall(commit)

searchObj
['351397', '0673d7', '68cf59']
```

here `(?=.*[a-z])` means "at least one letter".

but the result includes `351397`, there is no letter at all.

Why did it get only numbers without the letter?

Comment: I forgot to say, I would like to match a 6 digitals string, first and last digital should be number, but in middle, 4 digitals at least include one letter, others are numbers or letters.

Comment: `(?=.*[a-z])` means there is at least a single letter after 0 or more characters other than newline. It makes perfectly sense it captured `351397`. Maybe `\d(?!\d{5})[a-z\d]{4}\d` is more what you are after. That still is arbitrairy because you could more options depending if you allow for overlapping.

Comment: @JvdV, could you teach me how to realize my purpose? my purpose is to match like below pattern.  6 accd 7 6, 6 4c7c 8, 6 777c 8. something like that, please ignore the space in the example.

Comment: thank you very much JvdV, could you help explain your regex in detail?

Comment: not JvdV but short explanation `(?=.*[a-z])` is a so called positive lookahead and checks if after an arbitrary number of characters (`.*`) comes a lower case character ('[a-z]'). But it does not only check the match that follows but the rest of the line. So  `[a-z\d]{4}\d` the lookahead tests if anywhere after that point  a `[a-z]` appears . `(?!\d{5})` changes that in two points. One is that it test exactly the next five character (`{5}`) - so is not open ended and the the second one that it is a negative lookahead (`(?!`) testing that the next five characters are not just digits (`\d{5}`).

Comment: @Thefourthbird It looks like a digit, then 4 characters [0-9a-z] where at least one is a letter, then a digit. This would match the first comment too.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, the expression matches 6 digits because somewhere later on there's a letter in the string. The `.*[a-z]` part of the lookahead will take every character past it's present location and if it finds any character that's a letter, it reports "true" and the engine continues with `[a-z\d]{4}\d` which will match digits only too.

To ensure that at least one letter is present for a 6 character pattern that is:

- a digit
- 4 characters that are digits or letters, but at least one of them is a letter
- a digit

you can make the engine go to the middle of the 6 characters and check to see if any of the past 2 was a letter or if any of the next two is a letter. It's not the most beautiful solution, but it seems to work:

```py
\d[a-z\d]{2}(?:(?<=[a-z].|.[a-z])|(?=[a-z].|.[a-z]))[a-z\d]{2}\d
```

Breaking it down:

```py
\d                   # a digit
[a-z\d]{2}           # 2 characters
(?:                  # non-capturing group
    (?<=             # look behind
          [a-z].     # a letter and something
        |            # or
          .[a-z]     # something and a letter
    )
  |                  # or
    (?=              # look ahead
          [a-z].     # a letter and something
        |            # or
          .[a-z]     # something and a letter
    )
)
[a-z\d]{2}           # 2 characters
\d                   # a digit
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8gZxCJ/1)

---

The solution by [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68844123/i-would-like-to-make-a-pattern-4-digitals-at-least-with-a-letter#comment121667592_68844123) saying

> Maybe `\d(?!\d{5})[a-z\d]{4}\d` is more what you are after.

is, in my opinion, much more elegant, because after it takes the first digit, it checks to see that the next 5 characters are *not* 5 digits in a row. It will also work with checking that the next 4 characters are not only digits using the negative lookahead `(?!\d{4})` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
\d(?=\d{0,3}[a-z])[a-z\d]{4}\d
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/6UXt4n/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{0,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 0 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z\d]{4}               any character of: 'a' to 'z', digits (0-9)
                           (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
```